# Windows phone Lumia 535 with Windows 8.1 cannot update to Windows 10 via the OTC Updater at the moment

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, nokia-lumia-535

The OTC updater seems to be no longer working. Not sure though. Please help with a way forward. Asking for a client. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update service migrated to TLS 1.2 but OTC Updater doesn't support it.
You can still get OTC Updater to work by adding the following values to the registry:

**For 32-bits OSes**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
    "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
    "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
    "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
    "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
```

**For 64-bits OSes**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
    "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
    "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
    "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
    "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
```